# String to Date json parsing in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, serialization, deserialization

In `JSON` I'm getting multiple parameters, I want to use few of them.
So is this possible I can avoid parsing them, because I get `String` type of  "2018-02-09 03:05:20 EST" and on my dependent project from where I'm using POJO datatype for this is `Date`, I cannot manipulate POJO class(it is being used by multiple methods). I need method to avoid that parameter or way to take it in string format and set it in `Date` data type, without effecting POJO

Comment: So... you want to parse a date without parsing it? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: this i get in json
        "createdTime": "2018-02-09 03:05:20 EST",
        "updatedTime": "2018-02-09 03:05:20 EST",
String type
and pojo has
protected Date createdTime;
 protected Date updatedTime;

I dont have to use them, but when i recieve data, it gives deserialization error. at that time

Comment: please update your question with the information you put in your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store two variables inside your POJO class and ignore one of them when serialising.

```
...

private Date someDate;

@ JsonIgnore
private String someDateStr;

...
```

so when serialising and deserialising this will ignore the string one and produce only Date one. You can set Date `someDate` via a private helper function with the current value of `someDateStr`

Comment: can you please   explain more

Comment: assuming you get string and stored it in someDateStr you need to write a method like following one;
private Date parseDate(String dateStr)
{
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
return formatter.parse(dateStr);
}

set then call setter of someDate(type Date object) with stringDate parameter like this, setSomeDate(parseDate(someDateStr));